# which event(s) fires when an ADOObject (connected to ADOConnection) is destroying?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, adoconnection

i am trying to get an event from ADO Connection when an ADO objects is destroying.
i know ADO Connection has two lists to hold ADO objects pointer.
can i access their events?

Comment: Every component has FreeNotification/RemoveFreeNotification method to get the desired notification

Comment: yes, but in that case, we should ensure all components have adoconnection owner, but maybe not

Comment: Every component (derived from `TComponent`) can be notified on any component destroy. `WatchedComponent.FreeNotification( WatcherComponent );`. On `WatchedComponent.Destroy` `WatcherComponent.Notification` is called and you can override this method to do what you want.

Comment: if owner of ado object was ado connection, it is true.
but maybe not:
ADOCmd1 := ADOCommand.Create(Nil);
ADOCmd1.Connection := ADOConnection;

not works!

Comment: The answer to this question is simply "No event gets fired!" - To get an event you have to build an own class derived from TComponent and "register" all ADO instances to this. Now you can fire an event on destroy of these registered instances